# Video not loading in iOS 5 (invoked with unrecognized keys)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5

Hopefully somebody can point me in the correct direction with this error. I have an application that loads a video when a view becomes visible, and starts it automatically. It works fine in iOS 4, but when I tried to use it in iOS 5, it no longer works.

This is the message that it gives me

**2011-11-06 19:16:34.396 App[2923:16403] -[AVAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:] invoked with unrecognized keys (
    playable
).**

Here is the code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                 pathForResource:@"Video"
                 ofType:@"m4v"];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieStateChangedCallback:)name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:player];

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, -1, 817, 460);

[self.videoDetailView addSubview:player.view];

self.moviePlayer = player;

[player release];
}
```

Comment: Simple fix ... 

**[_moviePlayer play];**

/facepalm

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating an instance of `MPMoviePlayerController` in the `viewDidAppear` method, make it data member of the class. I think this may work for you.